# Is it possible to convert whole disk partition (sdx) to partition (sdxX)

Tags: partition, hard-disk, gpt

I have a extern disk perfectly recognized under linux but since Windows and MacOS seems not liking to have it set that way, I'm planning to convert it to partition. but I cannot find a way to convert it without problem.

So I'm comming to you for a working answer that will allow me to transform it to GPT.

Comment: Clearly the only way to solve this issue is to have a spare disk and copy everything on it, then reformat the problematic drive, and replace the old data.

Answer (score 0):

What file system are you using?  You need to use a file system that is recognized by all three operating systems.  [GPT - GUID Partition Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) and [MBR - Master Boot Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) are ways of partitioning a disk and this is probably NOT your problem.

I suspect that it is instead the file system that you are using on the drive that is the source of your problem and since you say the drive is visible by LINUX but not Windows and MacOS I believe your drive is using an EXT file system like [EXT3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3) or [EXT4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4).

After using Google to search for EXT3/EXT4 for MacOS it appears that MacOS doesn't natively support EXT3/EXT4.  According to [this](http://osxdaily.com/2014/03/20/mount-ext-linux-file-system-mac/) article you need to use something like [Fuse for MacOS](https://osxfuse.github.io/) to mount an EXT3/4 file system on MacOS.

You also need [similar software](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/) for the Windows OS to access EXT3/4 on Windows.

My recommendation is that you use the FAT32 file system which is natively supported by all three operating systems (LINUX, Windows, MacOS).  You might be able to find a third-party product to perform an in-place conversion, however, my recommendation is to use rsync to copy all of the data on the drive to a temporary location on another disk and then reformat the drive to use FAT32 and then rsync the data back to the drive.

Comment: it uses a simple ntfs filesystem. on older windows it works natively. microsoft clearly states that they have choosen to remove the support for whole disk partition. my question is clearly a "lack of partition table" problem

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your complete problem.  I'll probably delete my answer since it doesn't really answer your question.  You should add your comment as additional information to the question.  There may be a 3rd-party utility that might move the data, but your safest bet would be to move the data to a new drive and then partition the old drive either moving the data back or using it as another drive.